# Deportation from the US

Tags: usa, visa, united-kingdom, immigration, residency

I was deported from the US in 2017 at the Chicago POE after the immigration officer discovered I had obtained a B1/B2 visa to come work in the US for a short time. I wasn't banned but my visa was revoked.

I have since travelled to several European countries and returned home without any issues. My economic status has changed for the better too.

Right now, my wife and I are thinking of applying to move to Canada using the Skilled Worker/Professional Immigration basis. We want to make her the reference point for the application because she is more skilled and qualified.

So my question is, if we get to the level where I have to appear to get our visa/PR, would my travel history to the US affect our application and what can we do to prevent any negative outcome.

We intend to tell the truth because my US deportation issue was a big mistake on my part and an unfortunate incident that I have left behind.

Please your comments are welcome.

To present day...Thanks for reading this much!

We moved to the UK in 2021...my wife got a fully sponsored scholarship for her PhD and she's about to finish. We declared this deportation issue when we applied to come to the UK and we had no issues. We got the visas.

Now we want to take advantage of the United States' EB2 NIW route and so my question or my concern is about my deportation history and what we can do to not make it affect us. My wife is going to be the petitioner but is there anything you can advise us to do?

Comment: "I wasn't banned but my visa was revoked." But you said that you were "deported". Being removed on arrival automatically triggers a 5-year ban per INA 212(a)(9)(A)(i) ([8 USC 1182(a)(9)(A)(i)](https://uscode.house.gov/view.xhtml?req=granuleid:USC-prelim-title8-section1182&num=0&edition=prelim#substructure-location_a_9_A_i)). They don't need to do anything special to "ban" you -- it is automatic based on the fact of the removal. The only way you didn't trigger this ban are if you were allowed to withdraw your application for entry and voluntarily depart.

Comment: Further to @user102008's comment, people often use "deport" rather loosely, but usually the correct technical term under the immigration law of the country in question is something else, such as "removal" or indeed "voluntary departure."  This probably doesn't mean that you don't need to disclose it in your Canadian application -- questions about this sort of thing are typically worded fairly broadly, so you probably do -- but it does have implications, and you would probably benefit from taking some time to understand, from a more precise technical perspective, what exactly happened to you.

Comment: For example, whether you are admissible to the US will affect what flights you can book to get to Canada.  You may have to avoid itineraries with transfers in the US.  But then again the ban will have ended in 2022 so you can apply for a B or C visa if you want to transfer in the US.

Comment: Your withdrawal of your application for admission means you were not deported from the US. How you should respond to questions about this depends on how the question is worded. In all respects you should be wholly truthful in your answer(s). Because of the 5 Eyes arrangement, it's likely that the US already knows about what happened to you. Your application will be harmed if the US thinks you are dissembling or hiding information.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will be updating this thread if I have new information.